# How can I create 14 unique team rosters from 24 students in groups of 2?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have a class of 24 students, and they have 14 labs in which I have students partner up. I am trying to find a way to create a roster automatically such that none of my students has a repeat partner for the duration of the semester. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please recommend a tag I can use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of what's called "combinatorial design theory".  In your case you can think of this as designing a [round-robin tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) - the sort of tournament where everybody plays everybody - except you can cut it off after 14 rounds.  If you look at the section ["scheduling algorithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm) you can find out how to do this.  Basically, number your students from 1 to 24.  Then for the first lab you pair them up as

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13
```

(The 0s in numbers like 01 don't mean anything; they're just there to make things line up nicely.)  So 1 is paired with 24, 2 with 23, and so on.

Now fix the number 01, and rotate the other 23 numbers clockwise, so you get

```
01 24 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12
```

and so 1 is paired with 23, 24 with 22, and so on.  Repeat this twelve more times to get the pairings for the twelve remaining labs.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I just hope when a few students (inevitably) drop my class, it doesn't screw this up too much!

Comment: That's an interesting question, designing scheduling algorithms that are robust to students dropping.  I wish I knew something about this!

Comment: Yes, and the absences that will of course also occur. I'll test it out next semester and see how it goes without algorithmically accounting for any non-idealities. :)